# Image form title recognition/classification

Tags: forms, image-processing, ocr

I'm looking for a method to recognize scanned image form (something like bank deposit slip), which consits of rectangles and text. A sample: [image: link text]
<sub>(source: [immihelp.com](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/images/hdfc-fee-receipt-applicant-copy.jpg))</sub>

Image form: scanned images which were printed and filled out, this kind of form has title/rectangle borders/lines
Form title recognition/classification: identify the type of the form, by form layout or title or some other things, through many images which are scanned images of this form or that form

I was wondering if I can make it like this: get the title piece of the image by relative coordinates of the main borders or rectangles, then OCR the title.

Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It's been two years and no answer :( Did you make any progress? There are a lot of commercial applications that promise to do this: Accusoft, Nuance, Abbyy, Leadtools etc. but not much info on what they do exactly